# CATIA VBA Enable use of "Scripting.Dictionary" in .CATScript

Tags: vba, vbscript, catia

When running a .CATScript whose code was copied from the VBA environment and functions as intended when run in the VBA environment I get the following error:

> The scripting engine has reported the following error:
>
> Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error
>
> Description: Variable is undefined: 'Scripting'
>
> Line: 9
>
> Column: 4

How can I have this script use the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" reference library?

Comment: It looks like you haven't added it as a reference in your project yet.

Comment: In the VBA environment I have ticked the required reference's box and my script works, however When I copy this script to notepad and save it as .CATScript it will give the mentioned error. Maybe there is a way to create/export the required .CATScript directly from the VBA environment which automatically includes all references. Or maybe I need to add code to the script so that it calls the required reference.

Comment: If CATScript is like VBScript then you have to declare you variables as late bound.  If so, google for VBScript vs VBA.

Comment: I'll add an answer to my question, could you confirm if this method would solve my problem? (I can't check if it's correct because I'm no longer at my workstation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched on google for a bit and I believe the following would solve my problem:

```
'in original VBA code:
Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

'To have this work in .CATScript, replace the code above with:
Dim dict
Set dict = CreateObject _
("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution should work.

To be able to use "Scripting.Dictionary" in VBA, go to Tools->References and select "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".

Comment: I believe my solution will indeed work, however I still have one last hurdle to jump before my script will finally work (probably). I'm using a "Collection" in my VBA code. See my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282675/catia-vba-to-catscript-for-type-collection